# C - malloc and structures, segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, structure

im trying to make program that stores person's last name and name in a structure that is dynamically allocated and then prints it in terminal. For now i have got "segmentation fault" error after inputing the last name in terminal. How do i make it work? Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person{
        char *last_name;
        char *name;
    };

struct person *p_person;

int main(void)
{
    p_person=malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    scanf("%s", p_person->last_name);
    scanf("%s", p_person->name);


    puts(p_person->last_name);


    free(p_person);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p_person->last_name` doesn't point to anywhere. You were accessing memory that you are not even permitted to. You invoke undefined behavior accessing it. Solution would be to allocate some memory dynamically or use `char last_name[MAXLEN];` in structure.

Solution 1:

```
struct person{
        char last_name[50];
        char name[50];
    };
```

Solution 2:

```
 p_person->last_name = malloc(50);
 if( p_person->last_name == NULL){
     fprintf(stderr,"error in malloc");
     exit(1);
 }
```

In the solution-2, 
You should do the same thing for `name` also.
Free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it.

---

`scanf("%49s", p_person->last_name)` One less than the buffer size. When `scanf()` is finished parsing into a string, it appends NUL terminating character automatically.